# Can samba validate a domain user for a shared folder

Tags: samba

I can use `smbpass` to create samba users, but can Samba also validate domain users?

My smb.conf:

```
[share]
path = //
available = yes
read only = no
browseable = yes
public = yes
writable = yes
```

Answer (score 0):

The first step is to install winbind (If not already installed) a simple

```
sudo apt-get install winbind
```

Should do the job, but I cant confirm that while i'm at work. This is not be confused with winbindd which is a similar program.

Then you will need to edit a  file called /etc/nsswitch.conf to look something like this; [image: NSSSWITCH.CONF]

Then restart the winbind service.

Test that this configuration has taken effect by executing the command

```
sudo wbinfo -u
```

And you should get an output of all the user accounts you have created.

Then edit your /etc/samba/smb.conf file and include these lines in the global section;

```
   winbind refresh tickets = yes
   winbind trusted domains only = no
   winbind use default domain = yes
   winbind enum users  = yes
   winbind enum groups = yes
```

And then find the share that you want to validate domain users into and add the following line

```
 valid users = "+MYDOMAIN.NET\Domain Users"
```

This will allow any member of the "Domain Users" group to access the share in question, create your own groups and assign them here to restrict access to groups of individuals, id recommend against putting spaces in any group name (Or any other file/server naming convention).

This should work weather you are using the domain controller to create shares or a member server(To configure a member server make sure you follow this [Documentation](https://wiki.samba.org/index.php/Setup_Samba_as_an_AD_Domain_Member))

Comment: Thanks Dan i will have to fix my VB and give it a try... thanks again